# Phone vibrates only for first notification

Tags: xiaomi, miui, vibration, push-notifications, miui-12

**Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro, MIUI 12.5.1 (Android 11)**

When the phone receives a stream of notifications (e.g. 1 message per 7 seconds), only the *first* notification is accompanied by vibration - other ones go unnoticed. If the message interval is increased (e.g. 20-30 seconds), the problem will be gone - every message has its own vibration and it works well.

it doesn't depends on app - I've got this with WhatsApp, Telegram, VK, Instagram.

Could you please tell whether this is bug or not? How to deal with it?

P.S. I've got the same thing on MIUI 12 with Android 10 as well.